# Поэлементное соединение списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть два списка: `a = [1, 2]` и `b = ["a", "b"]`. Необходимо получить результат:

```
r = [[1, "a"], [1, "b"], [2, "a"], [2, "b"]]
```

подскажите как решить?

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Подскажем, только дайте нам ваш вариант решения и напишите, что не получилось

Comment: `list(itertools.product([1, 2], ["a", "b"]))`

Comment: `[[a, b] for a in [1, 2] for b in ["a", "b"]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения нужного вам результата необходимо пройтись по спискам. И поэлементно добавить в результирующий list необходимые вам элементы.

```
 x = []
 for i in a:
     for j in b:
         x.append([i,j])
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте вложенные циклы для перебора, и метод `append`, для добавления элементов в список

```
a = [1, 2]  
b = ["a", "b"]
res = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        res.append([a[i], b[j]])
print(res)  # [[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
```